# C++ Inheritance with pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to create a class that serves as a base object, which will then be sub-classed (=implemented) to serve various purposes.

I want to define one or more pure virtual functions, so that however subclasses the base class, is required and does not forget to implement them.

There is one caveat, the pure virtual function's signature includes the type of the base object. Once sub-classed, the function definition doesn't match the base classes definition anymore of course. E.g.:

```
class BaseItem 
{
public:
    virtual std::string getDifferences(const BaseItem& item) = 0;
}
```

So, in the derived class I'd like to do:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseItem
{
public:
    virtual std::string getDifferences(const DerivedClass& item) = 0;
private:
    std::string derivedItemCustomObject;
}
```

which of course the compiler won't accept. I could make it a `BaseItem` of course, but then I can't utilize any objects in the derived class.

Do I have to use casting to accomplish this?

Please let me know if my intent/question is not clear.

Comment: Yes, the common way to do this is to make the parameter a BaseItem, and possibly cast it as required in the derived classes, using dynamic_cast.

Comment: @ybungalobill @BoPersson [Look here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2950/152657)

Comment: @muntoo: [look here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/2956#2956)

Comment: If a method should not be called from the base class's interface, it should not exist in the base class's interface.  If the only reason you have for Base::getDifferences is "does not forget to implement", then Base::getDifferences should not exist.

Comment: @ybungalobill [Look here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37439/editing-for-brevity/37440#37440)

Comment: @muntoo: you removed one (!) word from a question of 150+ words, and backing it up by examples where people agree that it's OK to remove ~30 unnecessary words from a question of ~40 words...?? Not to mention that this word was not a greeting, but a single 'thanks'.

Comment: @ybungalobill OK, you win this round...

Comment: @Fred Nurk: What about classes that just serve as interface?

Comment: @LuckyLuke: If, given just a pointer or reference to that interface class (e.g. void f(BaseItem &obj)), I should not be calling that method (e.g. obj.getDifferences()), then the method should not exist in the interface.  Methods on a traditional abstract base class used solely as an interface are intended to be called this way.  That you want to change the parameter type is a red flag that you are treating them differently; plus you say "does not forget" as the reason, implying "so I can call them" is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **NO need to change the function signature**. Look at following:

```
class BaseItem 
{public:
    virtual std::string getDifferences(const BaseItem& item) = 0;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseItem
{public:
    virtual std::string getDifferences(const BaseItem& item)  // keep it as it's
    {
       const DerivedClass& derivedItem = static_cast<const DerivedClass&>(item);
    }
};
```

Can use `static_cast<>` without any fear because, `DerivedClass::getDifferences()` is called only for `DerivedClass` object. To illustrate,

```
BaseItem *p = new DerivedClass;
DerivedClass obj;
p->getDifferences(obj);  // this always invoke DerivedClass::getDifferences
```

If you worry that sometime you might end up passing any other derived class object as an argument to the method, then use `dynamic_cast<>` instead and throw exception if that casting fails.

Comment: This seems to be easiest way to accomplish what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @Eric, good to hear... it helps. However, be sure that, you are passing a correct type object to the function.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Suppose that the compiler allowed you to do this (or you do this by the means of a cast), then it would open the following hole in the type system:

```
class BaseItem 
{
public:
    virtual std::string getDifferences(const BaseItem& item) = 0;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseItem
{
public:
    virtual std::string getDifferences(const DerivedClass& item) 
    {
        item.f(); 
        // ... 
    }

    void f() const {}
};

class DerivedClass2 : public BaseItem
{
public:
    virtual std::string getDifferences(const DerivedClass2& item) { ... }
};

void g()
{
    BaseItem* x = new DerivedClass;

    // oops, calls DerivedClass::f on an instance of DerivedClass2
    x->getDifferences(DerivedClass2());
}
```

Your design is probably wrong.

Comment: It is not really a design, I am hoping that the answers here will help me come up with a good design.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the compiler accept but DerivedClass::getDifferences doesn't override BaseItem::getDifferences.  Here is a way to achieve what you apparently want

```
template <typename T>
class DerivedHelper: public BaseItem {
public:
   virtual std::string getDifferences(const BaseItem& item) {
      getDifferences(dynamic_cast<const T&>(item));
   }
   virtual std::string getDifferences(const T& item) = 0;
}; 

class DerivedClass : public DerivedHelper<DerivedClass>
{
public:
   // not more needed but providing it will hide getDifferences(const BaseItem& item)
   // helping to statically catch some cases where a bad argument type is used.
   virtual std::string getDifferences(const DerivedClass& item) = 0;
private:
   std::string derivedItemCustomObject;
};
```

but be aware that there is a runtime check which will throw exceptions if the argument isn't of the correct class.

Comment: BTW, it is probably the first time I find a use for the hiding of member function by a member of function with a different signature.

Comment: I'm unsure about the hiding after initially liking it.  Could be useful, but I'm leery.  struct SillyExample { BaseItem &x; template<class T> void operator()(T &n) { n.getDifferences(x); } }; // Do you want to prevent this?

Comment: @Fred, I'm sometimes unsure that I want static typing :-)  Always the same trade-off between expressiveness and safety.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to use a template and have the parameter be the type of the derived type

```
template <typename T>
class BaseItem {
public:
  virtual std::string getDifferences(const T& item) = 0;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseItem<DerivedClass> {
public:
  virtual std::string getDifferences(const DerivedClass& item) {
    // Implement it here
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use cast from BaseItem to DerivedClass + runtime check if given BaseItem is a DerivedClass instance.